# Calculated Column in Infopath

Tags: infopath, calculated-column-formula, form

I have the below formula that works good in SharePoint form but not in InfoPath form.

```
=if(AND(field1="", field2=""),"Not-Required","Required")
```

The above formula is added to a calculated column in SharePoint which displays the results post submission of form.

However I need equivalent formula to input in InfoPath form calculated field so that I can display the value even before the form is submitted to list.

please confirm if we have equivalent Xpath formula for the above.

Comment: Did you notice the spelling of "Feidl1"?

Comment: i'm sorry but the spelling in infopath form is correct and i guess there is no IF statement can be entered to a calculated field. I want an equivalent formula for the below to use in Xpath expression.

=if(AND( Field1="", field2=""),"Not-Required","Required")